# Does the .hgignore file work if commiting the folders that should not be pushed to the repo?

Tags: asp.net, mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

I've read a bunch of tutorials on this .hgignore topic but still haven't figured out it yet.

In my Asp.Net Mvc 3 app I have "bin" and "obj" directories that I don't want to push to the repository. I put .hgingore text file into my local repository folder (where there is also .hg folder).

```
syntax: regexp
/bin$
/obj$
```

also tried this:

```
syntax: glob
*obj
*bin
```

I've read somewhere that if you commit the folders (bin, obj in my case) the .hgignore file doesn't work.
Could it be the case and if so, how could I not commit these folders?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, .hgignore affects only adding new, unversioned files (and folders) and do nothing with objects already  in Mercurial
2. You can post-exclude hgignored patterns from versioning by using `hg forget`
3. If you want exclude folders and **all content of folders**,  not only root, your pattern isn't in best form

`syntax: regexp`

`/bin/**`

`/obj/**`